# Loop through array of objects, check for a matching parameter and add the matching object to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

I'm new to JS and React and I'm a little stuck here. I've searched through SO but I'm having trouble finding a solution with an explanation that works.

Here are my arrays.

The first array is pretty simple.

```
[1, 3, 4,]
```

The second looks like this.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: Title 1,
   },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: Title 2,
   },
]
```

What I'd like to do is search the second array and if I can find an id that matches a value in the first array, add the object from the second array to third, new array.

I've tried a number of things and I'm sure there's a relatively easy way to do this with a forEach loop or lodash but I'm coming up blank.

Any help and explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: `I've tried a number of things` Please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second array is not valid. You have to wrap the string values with quotes.

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

Try the following way:

```js
var arr1 = [1, 3, 4,];

var arr2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Title 1',
   },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Title 2',
   },
];

var res = arr2.filter(i => arr1.includes(i.id));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for continuing my education!