# Check and get data from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var Obj1 = {id: 1, name: 'Apple'}
```

And an array object:

```
var ArrObj = [ {id: 1, name: 'Apple', 'eat': 'rice}, {'id: 2', 'name': 'Banana'}]
```

How do I check Obj1.id in ArrObj? And I want the result to be: `{ id:1, name: 'Apple', 'eat':'rice'}`

Comment: `var result = ArrObj .find(obj => obj.id === 1);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through array of objects, check for a matching parameter and add the matching object to new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462062/loop-through-array-of-objects-check-for-a-matching-parameter-and-add-the-matchi)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Array.find()`:

```js
var Obj1 = {id: 2, name: 'Banana'}
var ArrObj = [ {id: 1, name: 'Apple', 'eat': 'rice'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Banana'}];
var res = ArrObj.find(({id}) => id === Obj1.id );
console.log(res);
```

You can also use array destructuring way like:

```js
var Obj1 = {id: 2, name: 'Banana'}
var ArrObj = [ {id: 1, name: 'Apple', 'eat': 'rice'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Banana'}];
var res = ArrObj.find(({id}) => id === Obj1.id);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @hieuphamba glad to help. You can tick mark the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: second answer doesn't work right now (it just returns the first element with a truthy id value)

Comment: @SandroKSG it does now

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `filter` function like this:

```
let result = ArrObj.filter(obj => {
  return obj.id == Obj1.id
})
```

Documentation is here: *[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)*

Answer (score 0):

all right!
you can also add array and get it by code :

```js
var obj = '{ "name" : "amr" , "age" : "16"}';
var obj1 = JSON.parse(obj);
alert("yourname is : "+obj1.name+" , your age is "+obj1.age);
// it get name > amr and age > 16
```

it's very easy :)